# Text mining python ou r

Tags: python, r, text

Estou tentando extrair informações de arquivos em PDF para popular uma tabela sem ter que ler o PDF.
Só que não encontro nenhuma referencia que indique como fazer isso.

Preciso, por exemplo, descobrir os autores e data de publicação deste artigo:

https://s3.amazonaws.com/academia.edu.documents/43803310/Completing_an_intercalated_research_degr20160316-636-na87j7.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIWOWYYGZ2Y53UL3A&Expires=1539106804&Signature=rSC0Kyg4%2FwXltsqiXG3eYuRmssc%3D&response-content-disposition=inline%3B%20filename%3DCompleting_an_intercalated_research_degr.pdf

Gostaria de dicas de pacotes/funções em python ou r.

Obs: já conseguir extrair o texto do pdf, o que eu não sei como fazer é encontrar as informações que eu preciso dentro do texto, dado que eu não tenho o texto exato a ser buscado.

Answer (score 1):

Arquivos PDF podem ter campos especiais para armazenar estes dados, como autor e data, mas eu abri o PDF que você mandou e nele estes campos não estão preenchidos:

[image: propriedades do pdf]

Então não tem mágica, você vai precisar parsear o texto e extrair os dados diretamente, já que o PDF não oferece esses dados de forma organizada.

Se você não sabe o texto exato a ser buscado, você pode fazer possilidades e fazer seu programa tentar cada possibilidade até achar uma que consiga pegar os dados.

Por exemplo, no PDF listado, você pode tentar comparar cada linha ao nome do PDF para encontrar o título completo, e considerar a próxima linha como autor.

Uma outra opção é procurar a sigla ISSN, e se encontrar, pode pegar o número e procurar em sites como https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nlmcatalog?linkbar=plain&db=journals&term=1175-8716 e extrair os dados que quer do site ao invés de pegar do PDF.